# Exclude \fullcite{...} citation from bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber

Is there a way to exclude a citation specified in the text by `\fullcite{Doe2013}` from the bibliography? (I'm using biblatex+biber.)

Comment: `\newrefsection` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are a number of ways you might exclude particular entries from the printed bibliography:

1. Set `skipbib=true` as an `option` in that entry in your `.bib` file.
2. Set a `keyword` for such entries, and print a bibliography excluding them with a `notkeyword` filter.
3. Add such entries to a category using `\DeclareBibliographyCategory`, `\addtocategory` and the `notcategory` filter.

If you are dealing with one or two specific entries, then (1) or (2) is probably easiest. If you want a **general** mechanism, then the third will probably be the best. Something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{fullcited}
\newcommand{\mybibexclude}[1]{\addtocategory{fullcited}{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

Chemists deserve numbers: \cite{cotton}. But historians get a full citation in the text
and are excluded from the bibliography: \fullcite{reese}.\mybibexclude{reese}

\printbibliography[notcategory=fullcited]


\end{document}
```

[image]

You could, if you needed this a lot, construct a new citation command that did this automatically. But it's probably overkill.

Comment: Great solutions! I tried the first and the third. The citation disappears from the bibliography, but there will be one missing number in the bibliography list (e.g. \cite{cotton} after \mybibexclude{reese} and the list starts with [2]). Any idea on how to prevent that?

Comment: Ok, I had to run latex-biber-latex-latex to fix the numbering. Thanks!

Comment: It's important to have the option 'defernumbers=true' set for biblatex.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old thread, but it somehow crossed my path today, and I think the question may benefit from another twist. The OP asks for the exclusion of a citation if it is done with `\fullcite`. [Paul Stanley's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111375/105447) gets the job done, of course. However, the three of his proposed solutions will exclude the entry, irrespective of whatever happens in the rest of the document. Even if the entry is later cited with `\cite` or another citation command. This answer proposes a way to exclude `\fullcite`s from the bibliography, but without hampering that the affected entry get to the bibliography if cited some other way. Of course, this may well be overkill for a number of needs, but may perhaps be useful for specific requirements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{inbib}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifcsstring{blx@delimcontext}{fullcite}
    {}
    {\addtocategory{inbib}{\thefield{entrykey}}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

Chemists deserve numbers: \cite{cotton}. But historians get a full citation in the text and are excluded from the bibliography: \fullcite{reese}.
%But may reach the bibliography if cited with a standard cite command: \cite{reese}.

\printbibliography[category=inbib]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you could even drop the `fullcite` toggle if you tested for the delim context: `\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifcsstring{blx@delimcontext}{fullcite}
    {}
    {\addtocategory{inbib}{\thefield{entrykey}}}}`

Comment: @moewe I hadn't thought of that. And actually, I didn't really know there was a delim context for `fullcite`. In any case, this is a large improvement, because, thus dropping the toggle, I can also drop the redefinition of `\fullcite`. Thanks!

Comment: @moewe, I tried to make this work for refsections too, but the `addtocategory` has global effects. Is there any such "marker" which would only be set for the current refsection?

Comment: Yes, categories are always global. And they have to be defined in the preamble, so they can't be provided on the fly in the document body. You can work around the fact that categories are global by defining one for each refsection, but that requires dynamic definition in the document. See https://gist.github.com/moewew/48eed49cbd1596d73ef8ebc720fc29c3

Comment: @moewe That's very nice indeed! I feared that a category per refsection was the way around it, but didn't suppose a definition on the fly was possible. I don't know if you think such revival of an old question is granted, but if I were to see that as an answer here, it'd certainly receive my upvote. :)

Comment: Its a bit of a hacky one. Especially the `\edef`, so I think I'll let it go for the moment. And your answer has already done most of the work, if anyone is really after the special case of a refsection they can find the answer in the link here or they can ask a new question and maybe someone knows a more stable solution.

Comment: @moewe Well, thank you for the trouble of exploring the question.

Comment: Somewhat related now - a `nobib` switch, matching `nocite`: Adapting this answer allowed me to exclude a work from the bibliography if it was *only* cited for a specific purpose (as an epigraph), and include it if it was also cited for any other reason: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113996/how-to-cite-without-an-entry-in-the-bibliography/538365#538365

Comment: I've not been able to get this answer to work, for some reason... which is a shame, because this is _exactly_ what I was looking for

Comment: @isolatedmatrix The MWE in the answer is working just fine on my end. If you can produce a non-working MWE based on it, you probably better ask a follow up question, linking to this question/answer.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution is to wrap the `fullcite` citation in a `refsection` environment to make it "local" to the position in the text where the citation occurs. Here is an example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

Chemists deserve numbers: \cite{cotton}. But historians get a full
citation in the text and are excluded from the bibliography:

\begin{refsection}
\fullcite{reese}
\end{refsection}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: biblatex fullcite example 1]

Then, if you want to cite this same reference later in the document in the usual way and have it included in the bibliography, you can:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

Chemists deserve numbers: \cite{cotton}. But historians get a full
citation in the text and are excluded from the bibliography:

\begin{refsection}
\fullcite{reese}
\end{refsection}

If you cite a physicist~\cite{glashow}, and then cite the historian 
later~\cite{reese}, everything works as expected.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: biblatex fullcite example 2]