# Add 'skipbib=true' to a .bib entry for one document only (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex

This question is a follow-up to [how to \cite without an entry in the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113996/how-to-cite-without-an-entry-in-the-bibliography).

I have an entry in my `.bib` file that I'd like to cite in my current document, but I don't want it to appear in my bibliography. I can tell `biblatex` to skip an entry in the bibliography by setting `OPTIONS = "skipbib = true"`, but this will make `biblatex` skip this entry every single time I cite this entry in every document I produce. I just want to skip it this one time in my current document.

So the question is, what can I put in my preamble of my current document so that I add `OPTIONS = "skipbib = true"` to the `lennon1970` entry?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "1970",
    OPTIONS = "skipbib = true"}
@BOOK{lennon1971,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Moving on",
    YEAR = "1971"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\citeauthor{lennon1970} published a book called \citetitle{lennon1970} in \citeyear{lennon1970}, cf. \cite{lennon1971} for more details.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the same result by using a `\DeclareSourcemap` for each specific document. Just include

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, match=\regexp{lennon1970}, fieldset=options,  fieldvalue={skipbib=true}]
    }
  }
}
```

to dynamically load the `options="skipbib=true"` for the desired bibtex entries.

Comment: Yikes. I was afraid the solution would involve ``\DeclareSourcemap``. The problem is that the ``\DeclareSourcemap`` command can [only be used once](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142837/declaresourcemap-in-biblatex), and I'm already using it in the ``.sty`` file I load as the style sheet for this type of documents ... ``:-/``

Comment: In the style you can use `\DeclareStyleSourcemap`, and you  should able to use both (untested:-)

Comment: Tested - and it works! :)

Comment: Other alternatives are: (1) add `keywords` to the `bibtex` entries and then `notkeyword` in `\printbibliography` (2) defines `bibchecks` and the `check` option.