# Citeauthor affecting sorting of reference list

Tags: biblatex, sorting, biblatex-phys

I use the \citeauthor command to name-call someone (C. Cuthor), say because they gave the name to some theory or model.
After calling the name, I want to cite the works of someone else (A. Author and B. Buthor), before I properly cite the work of C. Cuthor.

This will make the reference list and tags for the different works be unsorted, as can be seen in the screenshot for the MWE.

Is there a way to make \citeauthor not count for the sorting algorithm of biblatex, so that C. Cuthor is listed as the third reference entry?

[image: example code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}
@article{Author2020,
  author  = {Author, A.},
  title   = {The Importance of BibTeX in LaTeX Documents},
  journal = {Journal of LaTeX},
  volume  = {10},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {100-120},
  year    = {2020},
}
@article{Buthor2018,
  author  = {Buthor, B.},
  title   = {Advanced Techniques in LaTeX Typesetting},
  journal = {TeX Journal},
  volume  = {5},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {300-310},
  year    = {2018},
}
@article{Cuthor2015,
  author  = {Cuthor, C.},
  title   = {Introduction to LaTeX: A Beginner's Guide},
  journal = {LaTeX Gazette},
  volume  = {3},
  number  = {1},
  pages   = {50-60},
  year    = {2015},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=phys, biblabel=brackets, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

I'm here going to discuss the model by \citeauthor{Cuthor2015}.
It was based on earlier works~\cite{Author2020,Buthor2018}.
\citeauthor{Cuthor2015} completed the work~\cite{Cuthor2015}.

\printbibliography[]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there something that's keeping you from just hardcoding the author's name, i.e., replacing both instances of `\citeauthor{Cuthor2015}` with `Cuthor`?

Comment: @Mico not anything particular. I'd say it's more out of principle. Or if the Cuthor name is very complicated, and I want to ensure that it's correctly written and in accordance with the bib entry.

Comment: I suppose you could insert `\nocite{Author2020,Buthor2018}` before the first use of `\citeauthor{Cuthor2015}`. Not sure if this approach can be viewed as satisfying any principle, let alone principles...

Comment: Thanks, but not very satisfying, sadly ...
I have found this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/538365/281886
Adapting it to my numeric reference style and using the "defernumbers=true" flag mentioned in the comments to the answer from that page, it works if Cuthor2015 is not referenced later, but if it is, it still is sorted ahead of Author and Buthor.