# How to achieve full compression of references with biber and add comments to grouped citations?

Tags: biblatex, biber, biblatex-chem

I am working on a thesis, where I need to cite a lot of different papers. Following the regulations in my discipline, I need to group citations, i.e., a single number, for example (1) stands for a group of citations:

(1) (a) R. R. Schrock, .... (b) Y. Chauvin, .... (c) R. Grubbs, ....

Also, I sometimes need to add one or more additional comments in the way:

(1) This type of thing is described in: (a) R. R. Schrock, ...
    (b) Y. Chauvin, ....  (c) R. Grubbs, ....That type of thing is described in: 
    (d) R. R. Schrock, ... (e) Y. Chauvin, .... (f) R. Grubbs, .....

How do I achieve this type of referencing? So far I am using the following settings, but they don't seem to match my preferences:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper, 
final, 
12pt, 
numbers=noendperiod, 
BCOR=5.00mm, 
bibliography=totoc, 
listof=totoc,
headinclude
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
citestyle=numeric-comp,
bibstyle=chem-acs,mcite=true,subentry,loadfiles=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{my_refs.bib}


\begin{document}

Here I am citing a group of papers.\supercite{Person1,Person2,Person3}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

For an example of this reference style see:

[image: Taken from The ACS Page]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are really two separate things here, one doing 'simple' sub-entry lists with `biblatex` and the other handling complex note-like citations. As I'll need a demo bibliography, I'll cover both in one example after some explanation.

For the sub-entry lists, you need to use the appropriate `mcite`-like citation commands (`biblatex` doesn't add this automatically to the standard citation types). For example, for a superscript multi-part citation you want `\msupercite`. Unlike [`mcite`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mcite) you need to provide first a key then the list of entries.

For the complex note business there is no option but to do at least some of the work by hand. The [`notes2bib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/notes2bib) will let you run this into your source without too much complexity. What you'll need to do is use `\fullcite` or similar to place the full bibliographic data where you want it and intersperse the 'other' text. In the following I've reused the multi-part citation so it is automatically a list: for 'richer' cases you'll need to code in the `(a)`, `(b)` and so on yourself.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Grubbs2003a,
  Title                    = {Controlled living ring-opening-metathesis polymerization by a fast-initiating ruthenium catalyst},
  Author                   = {Choi, Tae-Lim and Grubbs, Robert H.},
  Journal                  = {Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.},
  Year                     = {2003},
  Number                   = {15},
  Pages                    = {1743-1746},
  Volume                   = {42},
  Doi                      = {10.1002/anie.200250632},
}

@Article{Herrmann1999,
  Title                    = {Ruthenium carbene complexes with imidazolin-2-ylidene ligands allow the formation of tetrasubstituted cycloalkenes by RCM},
  Author                   = {Ackermann, Lutz and Fürstner, Alois and Weskamp, Thomas and Kohl, Florian J. and Herrmann, Wolfgang A.},
  Journal                  = {Tetrahedron Lett.},
  Year                     = {1999},
  Number                   = {26},
  Pages                    = {4787-4790},
  Volume                   = {40},
  Doi                      = {10.1016/S0040-4039(99)00919-3},
}

@Article{Nolan2011,
  Title                    = {Synthesis of N-heterocyclic carbene ligands and derived ruthenium olefin metathesis catalysts},
  Author                   = {Bantreil, Xavier and Nolan, Steven P},
  Journal                  = {Nat. Protoc.},
  Year                     = {2011},
  Number                   = {1},
  Pages                    = {69-77},
  Volume                   = {6},
  Doi                      = {10.1038/nprot.2010.177},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs,mcite,subentry]{biblatex}
\usepackage{notes2bib}
\bibnotesetup{cite-function = \supercite} % Make notes use superscript citations
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

Here I am citing a group of
papers.\msupercite{metathesis,*Grubbs2003a,*Herrmann1999,*Nolan2011}
For complex notes, things need to be done by
hand.\bibnote{This type of thing is described in: \fullcite{metathesis}}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

---

As pointed out in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/comments/514175), to get the citation to appear only once in the bibliography, a bit more work is needed using the same approach as [Exclude \fullcite{...} citation from bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111363/exclude-fullcite-citation-from-bibliography).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs,mcite,subentry]{biblatex}
\usepackage{notes2bib}
\bibnotesetup{cite-function = \supercite} % Make notes use superscript citations
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{complexcited}
\newcommand*{\complexcite}[1]{%
  \fullcite{#1}%
  \addtocategory{complexcited}{#1}%
}
\begin{document}

For complex notes, things need to be done by
hand.\bibnote{This type of thing is described in:
a) \complexcite{Grubbs2003a},
b) \complexcite{Herrmann1999},
c) \complexcite{Nolan2011}.}

\printbibliography[notcategory=complexcited]

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I am trying to make more complex citations, I have the problem, that all references that are mentioned in the notes reappear in the references section, i.e. they are mentioned first in the note and then get a separate citation. Is there a way around this? With your preamble I tried the following: 

Here I am citing a group of
papers.\bibnote[metathesis]{For papers on metathesis, see: (a) \fullcite{Grubbs2003a} (b) \fullcite{Herrmann1999} (c) \fullcite{Nolan2011}} Here I want to cite this group again\bibnotemark[metathesis].

\printbibliography

Is there anything wrong the way I do it?

Comment: I found the following thread, that helped me solve the problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111363/exclude-fullcite-citation-from-bibliography

Comment: @Vlad030691 Hadn't spotted that: now edited in to make the answer more useful to others