# Refer to complex note-like citations

Tags: biblatex, biber, biblatex-chem

I have recently asked this question about complex note like citations:

([How to achieve full compression of references with biber and add comments to grouped citations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218947/how-to-achieve-full-compression-of-references-with-biber-and-add-comments-to-gro))

There, I was looking for a way to implement comments into my references, in order to obtain the typical bibliography used in chemistry journals:

[image: Bibliography in Chemistry Journals]

I like the solution provided by Joseph Wright, which uses `notes2bib` plus the `\fullcite` command along with adjustion that references referred to by `\fullcite` are not additionally included in the bibliography. However, I am missing the option to refer to the individual entries of the bibnote. Is there a way to add a letter to the bibnote number when referring to an entry in the way: [1a], [1b] ... For example by using something like `\bibnotemark[note1][a]` to produce [1a] and `\bibnotemark[note1][b]` for [1b] etc.

Here's the MWE from the Question mentioned above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs,mcite,subentry]{biblatex}
\usepackage{notes2bib}
\bibnotesetup{cite-function = \supercite} % Make notes use superscript citations
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{complexcited}
\newcommand*{\complexcite}[1]{%
  \fullcite{#1}%
  \addtocategory{complexcited}{#1}%
}
\begin{document}

For complex notes, things need to be done by
hand.\bibnote[note1]{This type of thing is described in:
a) \complexcite{Grubbs2003a},
b) \complexcite{Herrmann1999},
c) \complexcite{Nolan2011}.}

\printbibliography[notcategory=complexcited]

\end{document}
```