# Exclude \fullcite{…} citation from bibliography and bibliography-counter

Tags: biblatex, biber

I try to exclude fullcite entries from my Bibliography. I found this very useful answer [Exclude \fullcite{…} citation from bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111363/exclude-fullcite-citation-from-bibliography) but i have the problem that this excluded entries still impact on the counter of my bibliography.

As you can see in this mini example, the fullcite-entry still impacts the counter of the bibliography. But I want the Bibliography to totaly ignore the fullcite entries.

Greetings and Thanks for your help

p.S.: I'm using TeX Live 2014, pdfTeX, Biblatex

pp.S.: Yes I have read Wox comment 'run latex-biber-latex-latex to fix the numbering.' but this does not work for me, i have run latex many times and the numbering is still wrong.

[image]

A Miniexample for the Results above:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{fullcited}
\newcommand{\mybibexclude}[1]{\addtocategory{fullcited}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\cite{cite_max}
\fullcite{cite_anton}.\mybibexclude{cite_anton}
\cite{cite_lisa}

\printbibliography[notcategory=fullcited]

\end{document}
```

with 'library.bib'

```
@misc{cite_anton,
author = "Anton Mustermann",
title = "First Citeentry",
year = "2015",
note = "this is a note"
}

@misc{cite_lisa,
author = "Lisa Musterfrau",
title = "Second Citeentry",
year = "2015",
note = "this is a note"
}

@misc{cite_max,
author = "Max Mustermann",
title = "Third Citeentry",
year = {2015},
note = "this is a note"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[sorting=none,defernumbers]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{fullcited}
\newcommand{\mybibexclude}[1]{\addtocategory{fullcited}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\cite{cite_max}
\fullcite{cite_anton}.\mybibexclude{cite_anton}
\cite{cite_lisa}

\printbibliography[notcategory=fullcited,resetnumbers]

\end{document}
```

(You will perhaps have to delete the aux-file and recompile).

[image]

Comment: Great solution! Do you know any way to group all fullcited items using a command in the preamble, so that you don't need to add `\mybibexclude` every time? I mean not listing all keys, but use the fact that source was fullcited as a criterion.