# How to cite work and make it not appear in references?

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

I'm using `biblatex` to cite and reference previous works, via the external file containing such references (the `.bib`).

When using APA, if I want to cite an author whose cited text contains another cite (a "second-hand" cite), I should only reference the work I've actually read, and not the other. However, if I use something like

```
... there's some research done by \citeauthor{Tan00} \parencite[\citeyear{Tan00}, cited by][]{Vel13} that indicates ...
```

then I have to include both authors in the `bib` file, and so both appear in the "References" section.

Is there a way to use such notation and *prevent* the second-hand work from appearing in the references?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Should I include a MWE?

Comment: I'm not sure your assumptions are right. Anything that is cited should appear in the bibliography. It's not really relevant if you actually read it or not. Also, are you using `style=apa` for your references?

Comment: But if you really want to do this here is a duplicate: [Exclude \fullcite{...} citation from bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111363)

Comment: Thanks for the info! @AlanMunn, Indeed, I'm using APA. Well, I'm actually ambivalent about the assumption: Some guidelines I have read indicate it shouldn't, but none in English (in [this link](http://www.uces.edu.ar/biblioteca/Citas_bibliograficas-APA-2015.pdf) it says it shouldn't be shown).

Comment: I will check the other question to know how to omit the reference anyway, as it seemed interesting to me. So, where can I check whether the assumption is right or not?

Comment: I don't have a written source, but I'm a working academic, and this is how I would do it and how it is generally done in any of the academic literature I have read. The purpose of the bibliography is to allow others to follow the sources of the ideas that you talk about in your paper, not to show what you read. So if the idea comes from A and you get it from B you still need to give people a way to know what A is, so you say A cited in B and put both in the bibliography.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I'll take it into account from now on. For the time being, the question you've referenced solves the problem!

Comment: I can think of some good reasons for not having certain references in a bibliography. One example might be a meta-analysis or systematic review where analysis of the structure and outcome of many publications themselves are the subject of the research. One might want to show a large table of all publications as fullcites that fulfilled (or did not fulfill) certain criteria -- but it would not want to cite all excluded publications in a bibliography.