# How to omit one specific citation in \printbibliography, with BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

In my PhD thesis, if the chapter is already published  I need to state that "This chapter has been published as:......".

It's quite convenient to do it with `\fullcite{}` command. But then the problem is this `\fullcite{}` also end up in the per-chapter bibliography, which doesn't make sense for the reader.

Is there a way to specify that one citation should not be in the bibliography? (Like the opposite of `\nocite`)

MWE (my real .bib file is my whole library):

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{key1,
      author = {Myself, Me.},
      year = {2001},
      title = {Title1},
      publisher = {Publisher1},
    }
    @book{key2,
        author = {Author, B.},
        year = {2002},
        title = {Title2},
        publisher = {Publisher2},
    }
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{document}
    \chapter{A}
    This chapter has been published as :\\ 
    %(This \fullcite should not be in the reference list)
    \fullcite{key1}

    \section{section1}
    In text cite: \cite{key2}
    \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]

    \end{document}
```

Comment: The quickest way would probably be to add a keyword to this items entry in your .bib-file and use the option`notkeyword=<insert keyword>` for `\printbibliography`.

Comment: Have a look at [Exclude \fullcite{…} citation from bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111363/35864)

Comment: @moewe, as posed the question is interesting. Paul Stanley's answer offer methods to remove one (or a set) of specified _entries_ from the bibliography. But the question here is to omit one _citation_ from it. Suppose that one uses `fullcite` once, and for this citation it should not go to the bibliography, as requested by the OP. But later, the same entry is cited as `textcite` or `parencite` or whatever, and for this citation it should go to the bibliography.

Comment: @gusbrs my answer uses a new `refsection` and handles your issues (I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is another approach, which creates a command `\DontIncludeNextCite` with a self explanatory name and which will not affect other potential citations of the same bibentry. That is, this excludes the particular *citation* from the bibliography, but not the *bibentry* if it is cited elsewhere. It also allows you to work with `refsegments` (or `refsections` if adapted). Furthermore, it can be used with any cite command, not just `\fullcite`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,refsegment=chapter]{biblatex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{includeentry}
\toggletrue{includeentry}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{entriesinbib1,entriesinbib2,entriesinbib3} % you need as many as the number of refsegments in your document

\AtEveryCitekey{%
    \iftoggle{includeentry}{%
        \addtocategory{entriesinbib\therefsegment}{\thefield{entrykey}}}%
        {}%
    }

\newcommand{\DontIncludeNextCite}{\AtNextCite{\togglefalse{includeentry}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key1,
  author = {Myself, Me.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title1},
  publisher = {Publisher1},
}
@book{key2,
    author = {Author, B.},
    year = {2002},
    title = {Title2},
    publisher = {Publisher2},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}

This chapter has been published as: \DontIncludeNextCite\fullcite{key1}. % This cite will not include key1 in the bibliography 

In text cite \parencite{key2}.

Another cite \parencite{key1}. % But this one will

\printbibliography[category=entriesinbib1,heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{B}

Now, in a second refsegment.

This chapter has been published as :\\ 
\DontIncludeNextCite\fullcite{key1}. % This cite will not include key1 in the bibliography 

In text cite \parencite{key2}.

\printbibliography[category=entriesinbib2,heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{C}

Now, in a third refsegment.

This chapter has been published as :\\ 
\DontIncludeNextCite\fullcite{key1}. % This cite will not include key1 in the bibliography 

In text cite \parencite{key2}.

Another cite \parencite{key1}. % But this one will

\printbibliography[category=entriesinbib3,heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @StrongBad, another approach.

Comment: Handy approach, turns out`\DeclareBibliographyCategory` does not accept comma-separated list, and need to declare category one by one, then it works. Inspired by you, I came up with a similar approach: I declared one category for each of my own paper, say  `\DeclareBibliographyCategory{mypaper1}` 
`\addtocategory{mypaper1}{key1}`and for that chapter I used the `notcategory=mypaper1` filter, it works better than `notkeyword` filter. And in following chapters I can cite mypaper1 without problem. Seems the most straight-forward approach  for my specific case.

Comment: Also I doesn't have to mess with `refsegment` anymore which always give me pain:)

Answer (score 3):

Biblatex gives you the possibility to print a bibliography either without all items with a certain keyword in their entry in the .bib-file or only with the items with this keyword. The syntax for this is `\printbibliography[notkeyword=<keyword>]` or `\printbibliography[keyword=<keyword>]`. You should adapt your file as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key1,
  author = {Myself, Me.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title1},
  publisher = {Publisher1},
  keyword = {donotinclude}
}
@book{key2,
    author = {Author, B.},
    year = {2002},
    title = {Title2},
    publisher = {Publisher2},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
This chapter has been published as :\\ 
%(This \fullcite should not be in the reference list)
\fullcite{key1}

\section{section1}
In text cite: \cite{key2}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography,notkeyword=donotinclude]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for me by adding a keyword to my bib file by hand. Strangely it doesn't work in the MWE, perhaps something wrong with `filecontents`?

Comment: @LuoQi did you delete `\jobname.bib` between runs so the new bib file gets written?

Comment: For anyone having a problem with this: for me it works when replacing `keyword = ...` with `keywords = ...`

Answer (score 3):

As you are already using multiple `refsection` environments to get a per chapter bibliography and the `fullcite` reference you want to avoid is located in a predictable location I would create a new macro something like:

```
\newcommand{\prevPub}[1]{%
    \begin{refsection}%
    This chapter has been published as :\\%
    \fullcite{#1}%
    \end{refsection}%
}
```

such that your MWE looks like

```
   \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{key1,
      author = {Myself, Me.},
      year = {2001},
      title = {Title1},
      publisher = {Publisher1},
    }
    @book{key2,
        author = {Author, B.},
        year = {2002},
        title = {Title2},
        publisher = {Publisher2},
    }
    \end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\prevPub}[1]{%
    \begin{refsection}%
    This chapter has been published as :\\%
    \fullcite{#1}%
    \end{refsection}%
}
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{A}
    \prevPub{key1}

    \section{section1}
    In text cite: \cite{key2}
    \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]

    \end{document}
```

Comment: StrongBad, that's an interesting idea (+1). But if `refsections` are used in the document, wouldn't this result in nested `refsections`? (not allowed according to the documentation). Besides, it seems the OP is using `refsegment` to divide the bibliography per chapter. This definition would result in a `refsection` within a `refsegment`, woudn't it?

Comment: @gusbrs my answer works, it is not like I have RTFM ;)  I didn't know you cannot nest `refsegment`. If that is true and this fails in the real case, you just have to open and close the segment at the right time and choose the correct segments to print the bibliography for. I still like the idea of using `refsegment` as opposed to changing the bib file.

Comment: Thank you @StrongBad . This is actually better since my .bib file is auto-updated by Zotero. To use `notkeyword` I need to break the auto-update to have custom keywords. But what @gusbrs said was also true, `refsegment=chapter` option gives Nested `refsection` error (apology for forgetting to put it in the MWE). So I removed `refsegment=chapter`, used your macro, then enclose the whole chapter in a `\begin{refsegment}` environment.

Comment: @LuoQi you might just be able to change my `refsection` to a `refsegment` or just start the chapter `refsection` later.