# How to lookup the author's name from bib file, without causing the lookup to add a bibliography entry?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

To avoid/detect typos in author names I would like to use the bib file as a
single source for names. Please see the following mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{demo.bib}
    @book{articleA,
        author = {Author, A.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Alpha},
    }
    @book{articleB,
        author = {Author, A.},
        year = {2002},
        title = {Bravo},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{demo.bib}

\newcommand{\authorA}{\citeauthor{articleA}}
\newcommand{\authorAL}{\citename{articleA}{author}}

\begin{document}
 
The lookup seems to work fine using biblatex's \textbackslash citeauthor and/or 
\textbackslash citename commands.
The only problem I have is, that a lookup always adds an entry (here: 
[Aut01]) to the bibliography, eg.:

Hi, my name is \authorA.

Thus my question is:
How to lookup the author's name from bib file, without causing the lookup to
add a bibliography entry?

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick hack, wrap the `\citeauthor` in a refsection, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/645542/36296

Comment: Wow, that was quick and easy, and acceptable in general, too.  On the other hand the "quick hack" makes me think that there might exist a more elegant solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to omit one specific citation in \printbibliography, with BibLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403900/how-to-omit-one-specific-citation-in-printbibliography-with-biblatex)

Comment: The "quick hack" was more a "this isn't what this environment if for, but is an easy solution"

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz No, I don't think it answers my question: I tried to adept and get it to work, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hagJ939U seems to work just fine

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood you, and you me ;-) Sorry. I meant: Your "hack" works fine. I failed regarding the linked question/answer you provided in the comment.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz -- This seems to be asking for your hack as an answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm still a bit confused. It is exactly the same approach as this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403928/36296

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz -- Oh, perhaps my confusion stems from the fact that I'm not a biblatex user, so didn't make the necessary connection.  You're the boss here.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Maybe we just wait until the resident biblatex expert moewe can chime in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clean way to reach what you need is to create a bibliography category for the citations you don't want to print among the references and then print the bibliography without that category (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111375/101651)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{demo.bib}
    @book{articleA,
        author = {Author, A.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Alpha},
    }
    @book{articleB,
        author = {Buthor, B.},
        year = {2002},
        title = {Bravo},
    }
    @book{articleC,
        author = {Cuthor, C.},
        year = {2002},
        title = {Charlie},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{demo.bib}

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111375/101651
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{nottocite}

\newcommand{\authorA}{\citeauthor{articleA}\addtocategory{nottocite}{articleA}}

\newcommand{\nameauthor}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}\addtocategory{nottocite}{#1}}
  
\begin{document}
 
Hi, my name is \authorA.

Or, more general \nameauthor{articleB}.

Pay attention: if you want them in bibliography, use \citeauthor{articleC}, not the previous commands.
 
\printbibliography[notcategory=nottocite]

\end{document}
```

[image]