# How to make \citeauthor to not add entries to \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, imakeidx

I'd like to use `\citeauthor` as a way of mentioning the author when the work *per se* is not being referenced, while automatically indexing each time it's mentioned. I've experimented redefining it with `\DeclareCiteCommand` and didn't get the wanted result.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
  \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
    hyperref = true,
    indexing = cite,
    autocite = footnote
  }
  \begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
    @book{aristotle:physics,
      author     = {Aristotle},
      title      = {Physics},
      publisher  = {G. P. Putnam},
      location   = {New York},
      date       = 1929
    }
  }
  \end{filecontents*}
  \addbibresource{test.bib}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
  \makeindex[title={Authors Index}, columns=2]
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \noindent \citeauthor{aristotle:physics} [...]
  \printbibliography
  \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: you could add a category, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403982/2388

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers presented were extremely useful to gain an understanding of how to work with this. Both answers have their strengths and weaknesses. For the project I'm working with, the `\AtNextCite` approach will alter the years appending them a letter, (1980a) and the `refsection` will kill *ibid.* abbreviations and slow performance, MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}
    \let\oldciteauthor\citeauthor
    \renewcommand{\citeauthor}[1]{\begin{refsection}\oldciteauthor{#1}\end{refsection}}
    \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
    \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
      autocite   = footnote,
      abbreviate = true,
      strict     = false,
    }

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[1]{worman} then \citeauthor{worman} ipsum \autocite[1]{worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As a result, I settled with a solution where, authors of cited works can be added to the index automatically via `\citeauthor`, while authors that are in that same `.bib` file and are not explicitly cited will be manually controlled via a `\index{AuthorName}` command, providing good performance and producing the correct output:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
    \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
      autocite   = footnote,
      abbreviate = true,
      strict     = false,
    }
  \usepackage{imakeidx}
    \makeindex[title={Authors Index}, columns=2]
  \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  Lorem \autocite[1]{worman} then \citeauthor{worman} ipsum \autocite[1]{worman}.

  Other author \index{Aristotle} Aristotle.
  \printbibliography
  \printindex
\end{document}
```

It requires a bit more discipline and housekeeping and keep the final output without unwanted changes.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to put it in a special refsection that you never show a bibliography for:

```
\newcommand\mentionauthor[1]{\begin{refsection}\citeauthor{#1}\end{refsection}}

\begin{document}
  \noindent \mentionauthor{aristotle:physics} [...]
  \printbibliography
  \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot!

While this works for this MWE, it has the caveat of printing a lot of info, which slows down the compilation significantly in larger projects (~9 s):
```log
INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
[...]
INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 66
[...]
INFO - Processing section 1
[...]
INFO - Processing section 65
```.

Interestingly it's also not achieving the desired effect in a larger project, I'll try figure out if it's getting into conflict with something else.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, once you call a `biblatex` `\...cite...` macro on an entry the data of that entry is requested from the `.bib` file and added to the `.bbl`, which means it gets included in a bibliography if one is printed. With `biblatex` you cannot obtain the data of an entry without sending it to the `.bbl` and once an entry is in the `.bbl` it is added to a bibliography (if the bibliography is printed unrestricted).

There are some tricks around that that either involve several `refsection`s or filtering by categories or other data.

`refsection`s are one way to keep citations and the corresponding bibliography in one part of your document completely separate from citations and the corresponding bibliography in another part. One way to do that is shown in [pst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/48251/pst)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688838/35864) and a similar strategy can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403928/35864. The advantage of this approach is that it completely separates your "`\citeauthor`" call from the rest of the document citations: A work only cited here will not be added to the global bibliography and will not influence sorting or uniqueness calculations. The disadvantage is a processing overhead: Each "`\citeauthor`" call creates a new `refsection`, which causes helper macros to be written and read from aux files. Biber needs to process each `refsection` separately.

The alternative approach adds a `category` marker to an entry if it is only used in `\citeauthor` and then later skips those entries. Some thought is needed to get the logic right, but you can find an approach in [gusbrs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/105447/gusbrs)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403982/35864) to [How to omit one specific citation in \printbibliography, with BibLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/403900/35864). (I'm simplifying the code to ignore `refsegment`s for now. If you need them, the linked answer shows how to get them back in.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\newtoggle{includeentry}
\toggletrue{includeentry}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{entriesinbib}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \iftoggle{includeentry}
    {\addtocategory{entriesinbib}{\thefield{entrykey}}}%
    {}}

\newcommand{\DontIncludeNextCite}{\AtNextCite{\togglefalse{includeentry}}}

\newcommand\mentionauthor{\DontIncludeNextCite\citeauthor}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{worman}

Lorem \mentionauthor{worman}
ipsum \mentionauthor{nussbaum}

\printbibliography[category=entriesinbib]
\end{document}
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that for most intents and purposes the `\citeauthor`'d entries are still part of the bibliography: they influence sorting and uniqueness data. (Try `\mentionauthor{knuth:ct:c} \autocite{knuth:ct:b}` in the MWE above.)

Comment: Hey thanks lots!