# Remove footfullcite reference in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

For my thesis I want to use a bibliography as well as footnotes for simple links.

To keep the footnote consistent, I want to use `\footfullcite` and store the information in a reference manager.

The footnote looks like expected, but the reference also appears in the bibliography. Is there a way to remove the bibliography citation if the reference is only cited with `\footfullcite`

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111363/35864, in particular the second answer.

Comment: @moewe Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for.