# Print citation information, but do not show in references [biblatex/biber]

Tags: biblatex, biber

I would like to print a citation entry in my text body, but NOT have it as a numbered bibliography entry. I tried the `bibentry` package, but didn't have luck

**EDIT** I would prefer the solution to not require manipulating the bib entries themselves.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
  @Book{IncludeInRefs,
    author    = {J. Doe},
    title     = {Book of something}
  }
  @Standard{DontInclude,
  author    = {IEEE},
  title     = {An electrical standard}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}

We are conformting to the following standards:
\fullcite{DontInclude}

Here's a good book: \citetitle{IncludeInRefs}~\cite{IncludeInRefs}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. The following method uses a keyword in all the bib entries you don't want to appear in the references. Note, I replaced your `@standard` type with `@misc` as `@standard` is not a type in the default data model:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
  @Book{IncludeInRefs,
    author    = {J. Doe},
    title     = {Book of something}
  }
  @Misc{DontInclude,
    author    = {IEEE},
    title     = {An electrical standard},
    keywords  = {nobib}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

We are conforming to the following standards:
\fullcite{DontInclude}

Here's a good book: \citetitle{IncludeInRefs}~\cite{IncludeInRefs}

\printbibliography[notkeyword=nobib]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to edit the `.bib`, you can exclude on the information in the unmodified `.bib`, for example, the exact citation key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
  @Book{IncludeInRefs,
    author    = {J. Doe},
    title     = {Book of something}
  }
  @Misc{DontInclude,
    author    = {IEEE},
    title     = {An electrical standard}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibcheck{nobib}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{DontInclude}{\skipentry}{}}

\begin{document}

We are conforming to the following standards:
\fullcite{DontInclude}

Here's a good book: \citetitle{IncludeInRefs}~\cite{IncludeInRefs}

\printbibliography[check=nobib]

\end{document}
```

You can put any code in the bibcheck - filtering on entry type, other fields, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I updated my question however, as I would prefer the solution to not involve manipulating the bib entries.

Comment: Added example of filtering with no `.bib` changes.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted @PLK's answer, however my implementation is a bit different, inspired from: [Exclude \fullcite{...} citation from bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111363/exclude-fullcite-citation-from-bibliography)

I define `\fullcitenobib` which adds the `nobib` category to the citation, and then print the bibliography to exclude that category.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
  @Book{IncludeInRefs,
    author    = {J. Doe},
    title     = {Book of something}
  }
  @Standard{DontInclude,
  author    = {IEEE},
  title     = {An electrical standard}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}


\DeclareBibliographyCategory{nobib}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fullcitenobib}{m}{\addtocategory{nobib}{#1}\fullcite{#1}}

\begin{document}

We are conformting to the following standards:
\fullcitenobib{DontInclude}

Here's a good book: \citetitle{IncludeInRefs}~\cite{IncludeInRefs}

\printbibliography[notcategory=nobib]

\end{document}
```